# C++: using & operator for pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm teaching myself C++, and in the process I'm writing simple little programs to learn basic ideas.  With respect to "pass-by-reference", I'm confused why the following piece of code works (some of the code is just there to practice overloading constructors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Dude
{
public:
  string x;
  Dude();                    // Constructor 1
  Dude(const string &a);     // Constructor 2
};

Dude::Dude() : x("hi") {}
Dude::Dude(const string &a) : x(a) {}

int main()
{
  Dude d1;
  Dude d2 = Dude("bye");

  cout << d1.x << endl;
  cout << d2.x << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In "main()", I create an object "d2" of type "Dude", and use Constructor 2 to set "x" to be the string "bye".

But in Constructor 2's declaration, I told it to accept an *address* of a string, not a string itself.  So why can I pass it "bye" (which is a string).  Why don't I have to create a variable string, and then pass the address of that string to Constructor 2 of Dude?

Comment: Who said a reference parameter means passing an address? They must be executed.

Comment: While a reference isn't an address as far as C++ is concerned, in real life, it almost always is implemented that way. But references don't act like pointers at all. Well, hardly.

Comment: I changed the title to better reflect the question/answers.

Comment: Edited code to move constructor initialization outside of class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually illustrates one of the coolest and most useful features of C++: Temporary variables.  Since you specified that the string reference is `const`, the compiler allows you to pass a reference to a temporary value to that function.  So, here's what's happening behind the scenes with `Dude d2 = Dude("bye");`:

- The compiler determines that the best constructor to use is `Dude::Dude(const string &)`.  How this choice is made is a whole different topic.
- However, in order to use that constructor you need a `string` value.  Now, `"bye"` is a `const char[4]`, but the compiler can trivially convert that to a `const char *`, and *that* can be turned into a `string`.  So, an anonymous temporary variable (call it `temp1`) is created.
- `string::string(const char *)` is invoked with `"bye"`, and the result is stored in `temp1`
- `Dude::Dude(const string&)` is invoked with a reference to `temp1`.  The result is assigned to `d2` (actually, it is assigned to another temporary variable and the copy constructor for `Dude` is invoked with a const reference to it and *that* is assigned to d2.  But in this case the result is the same.)
- `temp1` is discarded.  This is where the string destructor `string::~string()` is run on `temp1`
- Control passes to the next statement

Comment: "bye" is not a `const char *`, it is a `const char[4]`. It *decays* to a pointer in the above context.

Comment: A subtle but important distinction, especially for someone learning the language who actually wants to know how the type system works.  Answer edited to include that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding what the `&` operator does in this context. Taking the address of a variable (`&var`) is different from signifying that a parameter is to be passed as a *reference* (as you have, in `const string &a`).

What your code is actually doing is implicitly creating a new `string` object that's initialized with the string `"bye"`, and then that object is passed *by reference* to the `Dude` constructor. That is, your code is essentially:

```
Dude d2 = Dude(string("bye"));
```

and then the constructor receives that string object by reference and assigns it to `x` via a copy constructor.

Comment: I think I see now.  In the argument of a function, the & operator has a different meaning than, say, when you initialize a pointer.  Also, there's a lot going on behind the scenes here that I didn't realize.

Comment: Exactly, the `&` operator has two distinct meanings in those contexts. In front of a, say, variable, it takes its address. In front of an identifier when looking at an argument, or after a type when declaring (like: `int& i = j`), that creates a reference and a reference is just assigning a new name to that same value. And that name can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `string` has a constructor which takes a `const char*` and is not declared `explicit`, so the compiler will create a temporary `string` (created with `string("bye")`, the aforementioned constructor) and then your `const string&` is set to refer to that temporary.

Comment: The one in question is created from "bye".

Comment: @MooingDuck ha whoops, those two words are so close and yet so far. Thanks, also feel free to edit my answer for things like that in the future.

Comment: I usually only correct typos when I'm _absolutely certain_ the poster has the right idea, and err on the side of comments.  Occasionally I'll add code examples if it's asked for and the poster doesn't add it fast enough.

Comment: So the creation of Dude object "d2" happens (above) by calling Constructor 2, which implicitly calls the string constructor to make a string "bye" and a pointer to that string, the pointer is passed to Constructor 2, which stores the value stored in that pointer ("bye") in d2.x?

Comment: @higgy not exactly. The creation of `d2` happens by creating a temporary `string` by passing `"bye"` to the `string(const char*)` constructor to get a temporary, then passing that temporary (by reference) to Constructor 2. After the constructor returns, the temporary is destroyed.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie:  I think I see; while initially "bye" is stored in a temporary string, at the end it is copied to d2.x, and the temporary is destroyed.

Comment: @higgy very close, but: the `char const[4]` `"bye"` is stored in the program somewhere, then a pointer is made to it and you pass it to the string constructor which makes a temporary `string` and copies `"bye"` and sets it's internal pointer to point to that memory, then you say `x = a` inside Constructor 2 which makes _another_ copy of the bytes `"bye"`, which is then pointed to by the pointer in `x`. Then the temporary is destroyed and you have only two remaining copies of `"bye"` left, the one in the program that is the literal `"bye"`, and the pointed to by the `string` in `b.x`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) There's no such thing as an "address" in your code. `const string&` means "constant *reference* to a `string`".

You're possibly confused by the fact that the symbol `&` is also used in an entirely different context as the "address-of" operator to create a pointer: `T x; T * p = &x;`. But that has nothing to do with references.

2) You're not actually necessarily using the constructor that you claim for `d2`; rather, you're creating a temporary object with your constructor #2, and then you construct `d2` via the copy constructor from the temporary. The direct construction reads `Dude d2("bye");`.

Comment: I agree with your first point, but maybe you should explain why a reference is *not* an address.

Answer (score 1):

When you call second constructor with a string argument, a temporary variable which references a copy of the string will be created and passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor 2 is not taking an address to a string, `const string& a` means a constant reference to an `std::string` object. The reason why you can pass the constructor a string literal is because the `std::string` class contains a non-explicit constructor that takes a `const char *`. So the compiler implicitly converts your string literal to an `std::string` first before calling Constructor 2.

So the following 2 lines are equivalent

```
Dude d2 = Dude("bye");
Dude d2 = Dude( std::string("bye") );
```

Also, when writing constructors, prefer initializing member variables in the initializer list instead of within the body of the constructor

```
Dude(const string &a) : x(a) {}
```

Comment: Okay, so for Constructor 2, I would put a prototype Dude(const string &a) in the class definition, and then afterward initialize it with Dude::Dude(const string &a) { x = a; }.

Comment: @higgy No, you should still use an initializer list. `Dude::Dude(const string &a) : x(a) {}`

Answer (score 1):

temporaries can be bound to a const reference, probably for this reason.

When you call `Dude("bye")`, the compiler sees if that is a perfect match (`char[4]`) for any constructors.  Nope.  Then it checks certain conversions (`char*`) still nope.  Then it checks user conversions, and finds that `std::string` can be implicitly constructed from a `char*`  So it creates a `std::string` from the `char*` for you, and passes it by reference to `Dude`'s constructor, which makes a copy.  At the end of the statement `Dude d2 = Dude("bye");` the temporary string is automatically destroyed.  It would be irritating if we had to do the explicit casts ourselves for every single function parameter.

Variables passed to a reference parameter will automatically pass their address instead.  This is nice, because it allows us to treat objects with value semantics.  I don't have to think about passing it an instance of a string, I can pass it the *value* `"bye"`.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor #2 accepts a reference to a `const string`. That allows it to accept a reference to either a pre-existing object *or* a temporary object (without the `const` qualifier, a reference to a temporary would not be accepted).

`std::string` has a constructor that accepts a pointer to char. The compiler is using that to create a temporary `std::string` object, and then passing a reference to that temporary to your ctor.

Note that the compiler will only (implicitly) do *one* conversion like this for you. If you need more than one conversion to get from the source data to the target type, you'll need to specify all but one of those conversions explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

While "&" is an addressof operator, when declared in as part of method definition/declaration, it means that the reference is passed to the method. The reference in this case is d2. Note that D2 is not a pointer, it is a reference. In the constructor, "a" represents the string object with contents "hi". This is a typical example of a pass by reference on a method in C++.